# Getting the current time in correct format - React-Native

Tags: react-native

I can get the Date function directly using moment.js but when the minutes are under 10 it will not display the 0.

**Please see picture below for example.**

[image]

the time is meant to be 12:02 and 12:03

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        datetimefinish: '',
      };
    }


  componentDidMount() {
      var that = this;
      var date = new Date().getDate('0' + Number()); //Current Date
      var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Current Month
      var year = new Date().getFullYear(); //Current Year
      var hours = new Date().getHours(); //Current Hours
      var min = new Date().getMinutes(); //Current Minutes
      var sec = new Date().getSeconds(); //Current Seconds

      that.setState({
        //Setting the value of the date time
        datetimefinish:
           hours + ':' + min
      });
    }

<Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.datetimefinish}</Text>
```

Comment: use moment.js instead or you can simply concatenate the "0" based on logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this if using moment.js to get the Date Time

```
componentDidMount() {
 var that = this;
 var date = moment()
.format(' HH:mm');
that.setState({ datetime: date });}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code and parse the string is you need some substring value

```js
var time = new Date();

document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML=time.toTimeString().substring(0, 5);
```

```html
<p id="time"> </p>
```

In your case you can use this code

```
<Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.time.toTimeString().substring(0, 5)}</Text>
```

An example can be this [TimeZone app](https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/MyLocalTimes/blob/master/app/utils/model/CityTime.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve with this:

```
...
that.setState({
        datetimefinish:
           `${("0" + hours).slice(-2)}:${("0" + min).slice(-2)}`
      });
...
```